# proof that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(x+n)}{x^2 + n^2}$ converges uniformily

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Prove that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(x+n)}{x^2 + n^2}$  converges uniformly for $x\geq 0$.

This exercise is in a text about uniform convergence, I've tried to use Weierstrass test with no success. trying to quote with

$a_n=\sqrt{x+n}/(x^2 + n^2)$

so that
$\ln(x+n)/(x^2 + n^2)\leq\sqrt{x+n}/(x^2 + n^2)\,,$

but then I can't find a criteria to prove that  $\sqrt{x+n}/(x^2 + n^2)$ converges (and if I prove this then $f(x)$ converges uniformly as Weierstrass test claims)

Comment: Your approach is incomplete. You want an upper bound *independent* of $x$ if you want to conclude uniform convergence as a direct corollary of the convergence of this new series.

Comment: It's correct, my best aproach is  ln(x+n)/(x^2+n^2)≤ sqrt(x+n)/(n^2), then again, I can't figure out how to turn this bound into x independant convergent series.

Comment: Did you try to find a suitable bound $\sqrt{x+n}/(x^2+n^2) \le c_n$ by distinguishing the cases $x\le n$ and $x>n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $(x+n)^2 \le 2(x^2 + n^2)$.

> $$\dfrac{\sqrt{x+n}}{x^2+n^2} \le \dfrac{\sqrt[4]{2}\sqrt[4]{x^2+n^2}}{x^2+n^2} = \dfrac{\sqrt[4]{2}}{(x^2+n^2)^{3/4}} \le \dfrac{\sqrt[4]{2}}{n^{3/2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks njguliyev, as you show the upper bound is of the form  ∑∞n=∑∞n=1/(n^p) where 1≤p. This makes the series convergent and so the series f(x) pass the Weierstrass test.